# SQLite IllegalStateException: where do I close the database?

Tags: android, database, sqlite, exception, illegalstateexception

I'm getting two contradicting Exceptions when creating and populating my new SQLiteDatabase in Android. In short my code:

**SQLiteOpenHelper extending class:**

```
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    db.execSQL(DB_TABLE_CREATE);
    loadLevelData(db); //puts data in the database
    //db.close(); <<< ?
}
```

In my activity class I instantiate this class (in onCreate()), and call getWritableDatabase():

```
dbHelper = new DbOpenHelper(getApplicationContext());
database = dbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
```

Now if I don't call `db.close()` after populating the database, like above, I get

```
android.database.sqlite.DatabaseObjectNotClosedException: Application did not close the   cursor or database object that was opened here
```

However if I DO close it, I get the following exception:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: database not open
```

on getWritableDatabase().

This really confuses me, so could anyone help me with what's wrong?

Comment: put code for loadLevelData(db);

Comment: Can you post the full database helper class you've made?

Comment: When you close db, you need to open() before doing any other call on DB. It seems you are not calling open()

Comment: @Waqas irrelevant I believe, only some insert statements. And thinksteep, getWritableDatabase() throws the 2nd exception, and so the only place I could place open() is immediatedly after close().

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You are not expected to close the database in the `DatabaseHelper` class. However you need to close it every time you open it calling `getWritableDatabase`:

```
dbHelper = new DbOpenHelper(getApplicationContext());
database = dbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
//... do something with database
database.close();
```

Comment: The getWritableDatabase() initially calls onCreate() in the helper, and from there I modify the DB. If i'd call close () after getWritabledatabase(), the exception has already been thrown.

Comment: `onCreate` is called only the first time you try to access the database - it is intended to create the tables and load the data in them. Whether or not `onCreate` is called is determined in the constructor of `SQLiteOpenHelper` and the database object passed in the `onCreate` is initialized before the call and **closed** within the constructor after `onCreate` returns. This is different object than the one you get calling `getWritableDatabase`. The second one you **do need** to close. Just try it - close it at the end of the method calling `getWritableDatabase`.

Comment: Ehm, somehow it DID work! I just put database.close() after dbHelper.getWritableDatabase() and it just worked. This confuses me a lot though, since the exception was thrown ON getWritableDatabase(), how could adding anything AFTER that make it not give the exception?

Comment: You did not get it quite correctly. What it says is that the database opened there was not closed. However, the exception itself happens at the end of the method (or rather when the value is garbage collected, but not closed). Read the exception once more...

Answer (score 2):

You are closing your database at the wrong time.

I typically keep the database around like this:

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity {
    SQLiteDatabase writeableDb;

    // ... 
    // Code
    // ...

    public void onStart(){
        super.onCreate(savedState);
        // Do stuff, get your helper, etc
        writeableDb = helper.getWriteableDatabase();
    }

    public void onStop(){
        writeableDb.close();
        super.onStop();
    }
}
```

Alternatively, wrap all your code working with that db connection in a try/finally block

```
db = helper.getWriteableDatabase();
try { // ... do stuff ... }
finally { db.close(); }
```

**Note:** All of the opening/closing should be done in the Activity working with the database, not the open helper.

Comment: "All of the opening/closing should be done in the Activity working with the database, not the open helper." - I disagree. My current app has a class which extends SQLiteOpenHelper - it has over 500 lines of code with over 20 methods (mostly public). None of my `Actifity` classes have any direct interaction with the database itself - everything is done through calls into the helper's methods.

Comment: Your solution is no better, and perhaps worse than mine.  Now you've littered a single class with all the responsibility of your database.  Since I took a terribly lazy approach, I get a database connection in the activity and pass it off to a manager which does all the fetching for me.  The better solution is to instead of directly working with the database is to use content providers which provides what I would consider the correct way to work with the db on Android. Sadly, I've found writing content providers to be painfully verbose.

Comment: "Now you've littered a single class with all the responsibility of your database." On the contrary - I have a single class which encapsulates all of the functionality needed by my other code (activities, services etc). None of them need to know anything about the database structure and can simply request data they need. If the database changes then I only need to modify code in the helper and the other classes carry on as before.